# How to update document with subdocument, or create new one if none are found

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

I'm trying to create a new subdocument object in an array when a user calls a command OR update the existing document based on their id. However, everything I've tried either gives me errors or it overrides the existing subdocument with the current user which is not what I want.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4XtMh.png)

Basically I want to add another object in the array ( "1": Object ) that is a second user tracking whether they've used the command or not.

I can't remember all variations on code, but the current code I'm using:

```
        const query = {
        _id: guild.id,
        members : [{
            _id: user.id
        }]
    }
    
    const update = {
        members: {
            _id: user.id,
            bot: user.bot,
            commandUsed: true
        }
    }

    const options = {upsert: true, new: true}

    await mongo().then(async () => {
        console.log('Updating to...in use')
        try {
            // Find the document
            await commandUsageSchema.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, options, function(error, result) {
            if (!error) {
                // If the document doesn't exist
                if (!result) {
                    // Create it
                    result = new userSchema;
                }
                // Save the document
                result.save(function(error) {
                    if (!error) {
                        // Do something with the document
                    } else {
                        throw error;
                    }
                })
            }
        })
```

is creating a duplicate key error which is frustrating. **Here is the layout of my schemas**:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const reqString = 
    {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }

const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: reqString,
    bot: Boolean,
    commandUsed: Boolean
}, {unique: true})

const commandUseSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: reqString,
    members: [userSchema]
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('command-usage-checker', commandUseSchema)
```

I'm using mongoose and mongoDB (of course) with javascript and DiscordJS.